# In extjs 6 remote Sorting is not correctly reflected on UI

Tags: sorting, extjs, grid, remote-server, extjs6

I have applied `remoteSort:true` in my store, as I want my data to be sorted on server side.
Server requires request in `Json format`. so I have used `beforeLoad` event to send json data.
I am able to send correct request and i am getting correct response as well(Checked that in fiddler).

Problem is that same result  is not reflected on UI, In UI i see it is sorted alphabetically.

I am not getting how it is getting that sort order when in response(Fiddler) i see correct sorting order based on date and year.

Comment: can you post some code here ?

Comment: I will suggest you to use `Chrome Developer Tool` to find web response from your API instead of Fiddler - https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/network-performance/resource-loading